# how do I give the class definition of the following class node here for a llist with and without a friend class?

Tags: c++, linked-list, nodes

I am not sure if I am doing this right, but how do I give the class definition of the following class node here for a list with and without a friend class? In which one do I use `private:` or `public:`?

Without friend class:

```
class node { 
public:
    el_t Elm; 
    Node *Next; 
}
```

With friend class:

```
class node { 
private:
    el_t Elem; 
    Node* Next;
}
```

Comment: but I am supposed to use friend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`friend`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/friend) is a specifier that grants  *specific function or the whole class itself* access to its protected as well as private members and methods:

```
class SomeFriend;

class SomeClass
{
public:
    SomeClass(int a, int b, int c) : a_(a), b_(b), c_(c) {}
    virtual ~SomeClass();
private:
    int a_, b_, c_;
    friend SomeFriend;
};

class SomeFriend
{
public:
    virtual ~SomeFriend();
    int AddABC(SomeClass& b) { return b.a_ + b.b_ + b.c_; }
};
```

> *What is its difference from inheritance, then?*

*`friend`* members require an external instance of the base class to access its members, while a derived class is already itself an instance of the base class...

> What else can be improved in the above code?

You could move the declaration of the class `SomeFriend` above `SomeClass`... and just do:

```
class SomeClass;

class SomeFriend
{
public:
    virtual ~SomeFriend();
    int AddABC(SomeClass& b);
};

class SomeClass
{
public:
    SomeClass(int a, int b, int c) : a_(a), b_(b), c_(c) {}
    virtual ~SomeClass();
private:
    int a_, b_, c_;
    // Making only the member function 'AddABC' friend of this class...
    friend int SomeFriend::AddABC(SomeClass& b);
};

int SomeFriend::AddABC(SomeClass& b)
{
    return b.a_ + b.b_ + b.c_;
}
```

Here, you don't make the **class the `friend`**, but the specific function that only requires its private and protected members...